# Spring Security with Webflow and JSF redirecting login page without error message

Tags: spring, jsf-2, spring-security, spring-webflow-2

I'm trying to write an application with spring security for authentication upon JSF and wedflow.

Below are code snippets.

**LoginPage.xhtml**

```
<h:form id="form" class="lgnfrm">
    <div id="LoginSection">
        <fieldset class="LoginBorder">
            <legend class="signin">SIGN IN</legend>
            <div>
                <div class="UsernameIcon">
                    <h:inputText id="username" maxlength="100"
                        value="#{loginCredential.loginUserId}"
                        onfocus="this.value='';"
                        requiredMessage="Please enter a username" styleClass="Width100px LoginTextbox" />                   

                </div>
                <div class="PasswordIcon">
                    <h:inputSecret id="password" maxlength="100"
                        value="#{loginCredential.password}"
                        requiredMessage="Please enter a password"
                        onfocus="this.value='';" styleClass="Width100px LoginTextbox" />                    

                </div>
                <div class="FloatLeft">
                    <h:commandButton id="loginControl" value="SIGN IN"
                        styleClass="signinButton" action="verifyCredentials" />                     

                 </div>
                <h:panelGroup rendered="#{viewScope.isLoginError == 'true'}">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{msg['auth.failure']}" />
                    <h:outputText value="Invalid Credentials!!" />
                </h:panelGroup>                
                <div class="FloatRight ForgotPWD"></div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>  
  </h:form>
```

And flow for this is

**login.xml**

```
<view-state id="loginViewState" view="loginPage">
    <on-entry>
        <evaluate           
            expression="new com.iri.rpm.web.ui.beans.authentication.LoginCredential()"
            result="viewScope.loginCredential" />
    </on-entry>

    <transition on="verifyCredentials" to="validateCredentials">
        <evaluate expression="authenticationService.challengeUser(loginCredential)"
            result="flowScope.auth" />
    </transition>

</view-state>

<decision-state id="validateCredentials">
    <if test="true" then="AgentViewState"
                else="invalidCredentialsState" />
</decision-state>

<end-state id="AgentViewState" view="flowRedirect:contract" />

<view-state id="invalidCredentialsState"  view="logout" >
    <on-entry>
        <evaluate           
            expression="new com.iri.rpm.web.ui.beans.authentication.LoginCredential()"
            result="viewScope.loginCredential" />
        <set name="viewScope.isLoginError" value="true" />  
    </on-entry>

    <transition on="verifyCredentials" to="validateCredentials">
        <evaluate expression="authenticationService.challengeUser(loginCredential)" result="flowScope.auth" />
    </transition>   
</view-state>
```

Service layer class as

**AuthenticationServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.iri.rpm.web.ui.services;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; 
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken;

import com.iri.rpm.web.ui.beans.authentication.LoginCredential; 

public class AuthenticationServiceImpl implements IAutheticationService {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager; 

@Override
public LoginCredential challengeUser(LoginCredential loginCredential) {
    Authentication authentication = createPreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(loginCredential.getLoginUserId());
    try {

        if ((loginCredential.getPassword() == null) ||  (loginCredential.getPassword() == "")) {

            // default it to something else;
            loginCredential.setPassword("xxxxx");
        }

        authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginCredential.getLoginUserId(), loginCredential.getPassword()));

        //authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
        loginCredential.setAuthenticated(true);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    } catch (BadCredentialsException bce) {
        bce.printStackTrace();
        loginCredential.setAuthenticated(false);
        handleBadCredentialsException(loginCredential.getLoginUserId());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        loginCredential.setAuthenticated(false);
        handleSystemException(loginCredential.getLoginUserId());
    }

    return loginCredential;
}

/**
 * Handle system exception and re route the user to login page.
 * 
 * @param loginCredential
 */
private void handleSystemException(String loginCredential) {
    Authentication authentication = createPreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(loginCredential);
    authentication.setAuthenticated(false);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
}

/**
 * Handle bad credential and re route the user to login page.
 * 
 * @param loginCredential
 */
private void handleBadCredentialsException(String loginCredential) {
    Authentication authentication = createPreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(loginCredential);
    authentication.setAuthenticated(false);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
}

/**
 * Util method to create pre authentication token
 * 
 * @param loginCredential
 * @return
 */
private Authentication createPreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(
        String loginCredential) {

    return new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(loginCredential, "");
}

@Override
public void logoutAuth() {
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
}

}
```

Defined bean as

**LoginCredential.java**

```
package com.iri.rpm.web.ui.beans.authentication;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class LoginCredential  implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String loginUserId;

transient private String password;

private boolean authenticated;

public LoginCredential(){
       super();
}

public boolean isAuthenticated() {
    return authenticated; 
}

public void setAuthenticated(boolean authenticated) {
    this.authenticated = authenticated;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getLoginUserId() {
    return loginUserId;
}

public void setLoginUserId(String loginUserId) {
    this.loginUserId = loginUserId;
}

}
```

Spring Configuration as

**application-Context-security.xml**

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:form-login login-page="/flow/login" default-target-url="/flow/login" authentication-failure-url="/flow/login?login_error=1" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/flow/login**" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/flow/javax.faces.resource/**" access="permitAll"/>    
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />


    <security:logout  logout-success-url="/logout.xhtml"  invalidate-session="true" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure" method="POST" access="hasRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR')"/>
</security:http>



<security:authentication-manager erase-credentials="true" alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>  

<bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" class="com.iri.rpm.web.security.RPMActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg value="infores.com" />
    <constructor-arg value="ldap://170.118.24.149:389" />
    <property name="userDetailsContextMapper" ref="rpmUserDetailsContextMapper"/>
</bean>

<bean id="rpmUserDetailsContextMapper" class="com.iri.rpm.web.security.RPMUserDetailsContextMapper"/>
```

All I have to say is its getting authenticated and going into corresponding flows when the authentication is done, the moment the credentials are failing its throwing the same loginPage.xhtml without error messages in it. Tired of trying couple of methods to resolve which didnt give desied result. Any help is truely appreiated.

Answer (score 0):

The error label can be found in the sessionScope.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message variable, so add in your loggin page : ${sessionScope.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message} and the error message will be displayed.